# getting Boost working in centos 5.5

Tags: c++

This sounds like it should be simple, but it is proving to be impossible to accomplish.

I installed with the following command:

sudo yum install boost boost-devel boost-doc

Then, I started to added the following to my header file

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
```

and I promptly got the following error:

error: boost/filesystem.hpp: No such file or directory

I know that boost is partially working because when I use this header:

```
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
```

i don't get compilation issues.

I know that I need to somehow build certain libraries like filesystem

However, I have not been able to find instructions anywhere on the entire internet for how to do this for CentOS 5.  There is no bootstrap.sh or ./bjam for me to use.

Comment: does that file exist? type `locate filesystem.hpp` and if locate doesn't exist, type `sudo yum install locate`. Finally if it finds the file, create a sym link to the boost directory. `ln -s <path_from_locate> boost/filesystem.hpp`

Comment: What command are you using to compile?

Answer (score 1):

I just looked at the RHEL 5.5 RPM for `boost-devel`, and it is missing `/usr/include/boost/filesystem.hpp`.  The RPMs have Boost 1.33.1, and that version did not have `boost/filesystem.hpp` in it.  You should upgrade to a newer version of Boost or write your code using the documentation for Boost 1.33.1 (available at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_33_1/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm).

Comment: Ah, it appears the standard version of Boost that comes with CentOS is somewhat outdated.